# EIDE/SATA adapter issue

Tags: hard-drive

I have an EIDE hard drive and a docking station for Sata (with a USB connection), what cable would I need to connect the EIDE hard drive to the SATA docking station and how much would it cost?

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is an "IDE to SATA converter". They can be found for around $15 to $20. Just Google it and you find plenty of suppliers.

Please note: Due to the size of the converter it may not physically fit in your dock. These things are designed to make an old IDE drive mounted in a PC case work with modern SATA only motherboard.
The better ones come with a short IDE cable which may be useful to lay the disk flat on a table while the converter sits in the dock.

However:
An USB3 to a combined IDE and SATA converter costs about the same or is slightly more expensive. USB docks with both IDE and SATA are also available.
I would strongly advise to go for such a combined IDE and SATA converter/dock. IDE to SATA conversion is a rather unnatural thing to do and doesn't always work reliably with all IDE drives.
The USB to IDE/SATA converters do things in a slightly different way internally, which usually provides better IDE compatibility, especially for really old IDE drives.
They usually also deal better with read-errors on drives, which is certainly a concern with very old drives.

Comment: This answer focuses solely on the data/control cables of SATA and (E)IDE/PATA, while ignoring the different power connectors of SATA and (E)IDE drives.   BTW *"lay the disk flat on a table"* is not ideal, and subjects the HDD to potential shock and vibrations.  Don't bother responding that you have done this many times without problems.  See https://superuser.com/questions/1510488/solution-for-mounting-hard-drive-better-on-desk-to-prevent-sata-cable-wear/1510530#1510530

Comment: @sawdust These converters nearly always come with power adapters included. And obviously the wrong power plug won’t fit no matter how much you force things. And I especially mentioned possible mounting problems. Having it flat on a table is to be preferred to vertical stacking in a dock+converter. I really don’t see a reason for a downvote.